# Trying to use Coroutine to activate and deactivate objects in the scene in VR development

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, coroutine

I'm designing a VR game and I'm trying to make a menu that attaches to the left controller. I have two buttons, one is used to activate a few objects in the scene, and the other one is used to take the player to a different scene.

I've been looking at the SteamVR Interactive Sample and I'm trying to mimic the buttons they have used in Sample Scene. Except in the sample they are using Coroutine to start different hints on the controller so they are using the Hand class. I'm just trying to use it to activate and deactivate objects and more to a different scene.

Just to make things clear these are the things I'm trying to achieve:

1. When user hits the first button, activate the object (obj1) that is specified through the Inspector tab in Unity.
2. When user hits the second button, deactivate the objects (obj1) and move to a different scene.

Here is the C# code that's in the Sample scene. It has three buttons and they either activate "Button Hints" or "Text Hints":

```C#
//======= Copyright (c) Valve Corporation, All rights reserved. ===============
//
// Purpose: Demonstrates the use of the controller hint system
//
//=============================================================================

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Valve.VR;

namespace Valve.VR.InteractionSystem
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class ControllerHintsExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Coroutine buttonHintCoroutine;
        private Coroutine textHintCoroutine;

        //-------------------------------------------------
        public void ShowButtonHints( Hand hand )
        {
            if ( buttonHintCoroutine != null )
            {
                StopCoroutine( buttonHintCoroutine );
            }
            buttonHintCoroutine = StartCoroutine( TestButtonHints( hand ) );
        }


        //-------------------------------------------------
        public void ShowTextHints( Hand hand )
        {
            if ( textHintCoroutine != null )
            {
                StopCoroutine( textHintCoroutine );
            }
            textHintCoroutine = StartCoroutine( TestTextHints( hand ) );
        }


        //-------------------------------------------------
        public void DisableHints()
        {
            if ( buttonHintCoroutine != null )
            {
                StopCoroutine( buttonHintCoroutine );
                buttonHintCoroutine = null;
            }

            if ( textHintCoroutine != null )
            {
                StopCoroutine( textHintCoroutine );
                textHintCoroutine = null;
            }

            foreach ( Hand hand in Player.instance.hands )
            {
                ControllerButtonHints.HideAllButtonHints( hand );
                ControllerButtonHints.HideAllTextHints( hand );
            }
        }


        //-------------------------------------------------
        // Cycles through all the button hints on the controller
        //-------------------------------------------------
        private IEnumerator TestButtonHints( Hand hand )
        {
            ControllerButtonHints.HideAllButtonHints( hand );

            while ( true )
            {
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowButtonHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_ApplicationMenu );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowButtonHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_System );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowButtonHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Grip );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowButtonHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowButtonHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.0f );

                ControllerButtonHints.HideAllButtonHints( hand );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.0f );
            }
        }


        //-------------------------------------------------
        // Cycles through all the text hints on the controller
        //-------------------------------------------------
        private IEnumerator TestTextHints( Hand hand )
        {
            ControllerButtonHints.HideAllTextHints( hand );

            while ( true )
            {
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowTextHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_ApplicationMenu, "Application" );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowTextHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_System, "System" );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowTextHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Grip, "Grip" );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowTextHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger, "Trigger" );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );
                ControllerButtonHints.ShowTextHint( hand, EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad, "Touchpad" );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );

                ControllerButtonHints.HideAllTextHints( hand );
                yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have which is similar copy of the sample code. I got stuck at figuring out the object activation and haven't touched scene change yet:

```C#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Valve.VR;

namespace Valve.VR.InteractionSystem
{
    //................................................
    public class HandMenueActions : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject AllProducts;

        private Coroutine allProductsCoroutine;
        private Coroutine aboutUsCoroutine;

        //............................................
        public void ShowAllProducts(GameObject AllProducts)
        {
            if (allProductsCoroutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(allProductsCoroutine);
            }
            allProductsCoroutine = StartCoroutine(TestAllProducts);
        }


        //............................................
        //Turns on all products in the scene
        //............................................
        private IEnumerable TestAllProducts()
        {
            AllProducts.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

I'm not that experienced and I try to write code for unity with the documentation open right next to it but I'm still here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to use Coroutines for that instead of simple methods ..

To be honest I don't know in specific the `Valve.VR.InteractionSystem`

But I would just do simple methods like:

```
public GameObject obj1;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButton("Button1") // or however you access your button 1
    {
        obj1.SetActive(true);
    } else if (Input.GetButton("Button2") // or however you access your button2
    {
        obj1.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I use else there so only one button press is executed at the same time.

---

In a quick search I now also found an [Unity manual for SteamVr controler input](https://unity3d.college/2016/11/16/steamvr-controller-input/).

They have a complete example using event handlers/callbacks. Here is a shortened one that should fit your need (they also explain quite well how it all works)

```
using UnityEngine; 

public class ObjectEnabler : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private SteamVR_TrackedController _controller;  

    public GameObject obj1;

    private void OnEnable() 
    {       
        // Get the controller this component is attached to
        _controller = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedController>();    

        // Register callbacks to your buttons
        // I've left this on the ones from the example .. if you need others 
        // You have to look them up
        // In the example there is also a complete list of all button events
        RegisterCallbacks();
    }   

    private void OnDisable()    
    {       
        UnregisterCallbacks();
    }

    // Register callbacks for controler events
    private void RegisterCallbacks()
    {
        // It is always save to remove callbacks 
        // So just to be sure we only register once so methods are not executed twice
        // I personaly always first unregister callbacks:
        UnregisterCallbacks();

        // now I register the callback that means e.g.
        // Everytime the event TriggerClicked is 
        // invoked anywhere in the Scene I want to execute HandleTrickerClicked
        // hint the method can be called as you like .. could also simply be EnableObject e.g.
        _controller.TriggerClicked += HandleTriggerClicked;     
        _controller.PadClicked += HandlePadClicked; 
        // For more information how the callbacks work
        // see the link I provided
    }

    // Unregister callbacks for events
    private void UnregisterCallbacks()
    {
        _controller.TriggerClicked -= HandleTriggerClicked;     
        _controller.PadClicked -= HandlePadClicked; 
    }

    // Called on TriggerClicked
    // Enables the obj1
    private void HandleTriggerClicked() 
    {
        obj1.SetActive(true);
    }   

    // Called on PadClicked
    // Disables the obj1
    private void HandlePadClicked()
    {
        obj1.SetActive(false);
    } 
}
```

You now just have to attach this script to a controller (next to a `SteamVR_TrackedController` Component) and it should do what you wanted.

(I'm not sure right now because I never used it and I'm on a mobile but their script might eventually miss some `using` namespaces e.g. starting with the entire `using Valve.VR;` stuff but I don't know how exactly this is implemented)

Comment: So I don't have a preference on what to use. I tried writing my own thing that's similar to yours but I had problem either getting it to connect to the controllers, or the code functioning. But I think after I look more closely into the Unity code you shared I should be able to figure it out. Thanks a lot